# Using an anonymous delegate to return an object

Tags: c#, delegates, language-features

Is it possible to use an anonymous delegate to return an object?

Something like so:

```
object b = delegate { return a; };
```

Comment: Where does `a` come from? Also your existing code simply assigns `b` to the delegate itself.

Comment: @BoltClock - thanks for pointing out the assignment issue.

Comment: see the update re your cross-threading pain

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, but only by invoking it:

```
Func<object> func = delegate { return a; };
// or Func<object> func = () => a;
object b = func();
```

And of course, the following is a lot simpler...

```
object b = a;
```

---

In the comments, cross-thread exceptions are mentioned; this can be fixed as follows:

If the delegate is the thing we want to run back on the UI thread *from* a BG thread:

```
object o = null;
MethodInvoker mi = delegate {
    o = someControl.Value; // runs on UI
};
someControl.Invoke(mi);
// now read o
```

Or the other way around (to run the delegate on a BG):

```
object value = someControl.Value;
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate {
    // can talk safely to "value", but not to someControl
});
```

Comment: and if i'm trying to compare `a` with some other object within a method on a thread other than the thread in which `a` belongs? For instance, `void Test() { if(a == b){} }` where accessing b from this method causes a cross-thread exception.

Comment: @Wulfgar `a` doesn't "belong" to a thread; it belongs either to a class instance (if it is a field), or is a method variable. Either way, the compiler will "capture" the `a` variable from the scope that declares the delegate; by creating a type that encapsulates either the object instance "this" (for a field), or the "variable" itself; quoted because it then *becomes* a field.

Comment: @Wulfgar - to get a cross-thread, you must be doing UI work; yes, you can fix this, but "how" depends on which block of code is the UI code; can you clarify that please?

Answer (score 1):

Just declare somewhere these static functions:

```
public delegate object AnonymousDelegate();

public static object GetDelegateResult(AnonymousDelegate function)
{
    return function.Invoke();
}
```

And anywhere use it as you want like this:

```
object item = GetDelegateResult(delegate { return "TEST"; });
```

or even like this

```
object item = ((AnonymousDelegate)delegate { return "TEST"; }).Invoke();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;

public delegate int ReturnedDelegate(string s);

class AnonymousDelegate
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ReturnedDelegate len = delegate(string s)
        {
            return s.Length;
        };
        Console.WriteLine(len("hello world"));
    }
}
```